# Representations of a Function of a random variable

Tags: probability, group-theory, functions, transformation, diffeomorphism

Assume we have a real random variable $Y\in \mathbb R^p$, such that $Y= g(X)$ where $X \in\mathbb  R^n $, $n< p$, is some random variable with continuous distribution $P$ and $g:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow\mathbb  R^p$ is some smooth function (with continuous derivatives and second derivatives).

Obviously, the representation of $Y$ is not unique, we can find $\tilde g$ and $\tilde X$ satisfying $Y =\tilde g(\tilde X)$ just by defining an invertible map $H$ with $\tilde g = g\circ H$ and $\tilde X = H^{-1}(X)$.

I would like to know if there are other smooth $\tilde g$ and $\tilde X$ satisfying $Y =\tilde g(\tilde X)$  ?

Comment: Sure, let $\widetilde{g}$ be the identity map on $\mathbb{R}^p$ and let $\widetilde{X}=Y$.

Comment: That's true, thanks! But it is possible only if $n = p$. I updated the questions. Thanks a lot.